# firefox debugger not displayed scope value

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I try to understand how new firefox debugger works. I look this tuto : [firefox debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/UI_Tour) but with my website and JS file I can't look value of the variable js. My code it is so simple but I never look a scope or value in debugger

Js file I want to debug and launched by my website page :

```
$(document).ready( function (){

$('.collapse').collapse({
    show: false
});

$(function(){
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});

$('#datatable').DataTable({
    scrollY:        '50vh',
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging:         false
});

function getTree() {

    console.log('OK');

    var toto = 'tata';


    var url = Routing.generate('app_parametrage_list_categorie_xhr');

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(result){
            console.log('OK');
    }});

    return data;
}

$('#tree').treeview({data: getTree()});
```

});

[image]

Comment: Can you share your website/code so we can help with the debugger?

Comment: That screen shot says that the program is running.  You can only see the contents of variables when the program is stopped at some breakpoint.  So, you have to take whatever action it is that will cause that function to be called, so the breakpoint can trigger.

Comment: I try other breakpoint out of my function with program running or not but I never view variable value displayed. Nothing happend breakpoint or not.